# Calendar Forms still loading via Dialog, despite Advanced List Setting saved?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, calendar, modal-dialog

I've got a problem where, it seems the 'Add Event' option within an SharePoint 2013 Calendar is *always* using a dialog to add an Event.

[image: Meeting room Dialog]

***Despite*** I've repeatedly saved the 'Advanced Setting' for: "Launch forms in a dialog?"

[image: Launch forms in a Dialog Picture]

I'm *needing* this to take me to a new page instead of a dialogue box to display the form, as I do believe this *was* possible to do in SharePoint 2010.

Am I missing something obvious here? Or is it that, in SharePoint 2013 it's simply not possible to open on a new page for this Calendar form?

Comment: Have you checked if you see the same behavior for a custom list ?

Comment: @CameronVerhelst Thanks for the suggestion! Created a custom list with a two-field input and indeed, it's listening to the `Launch forms in a dialog` option correctly; going to a new page when *not* and a dialog when ticked yes. Which makes me think If I were to re-create the list, as this Calendar list was migrated from SharePoint 2010 (I should of added that) it might work.

Comment: Could it have to do with the way you add the event to the calendar ? Have you tried doing it from the add new item link from a different view ?

Comment: Or it may be a left-over from the migration :), good catch!

Comment: @CameronVerhelst It works from views other-than-calendar; which seems to be a pain! Alas, looks like I'll have to make do :) Thank you for your help Cameron!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not missing anything. This behaviour is present only for calendar views and setting "Launch forms in a modal dialog?" to No has no effect. If you create a standard view for the calendar list the forms will open in a new page. 
Probably its a bug in the view's javascript code. Calendar views have much more javascript code compared to standard views.
You can dive in the view's javascript and find the part that opens the dialog and maybe it can be fixed with some javascript (maybe by setting a variable...).

Comment: Sadly this seems to be true, I've attempted every other-view type apart from Calendar and it does work. Although as you've explained, Standard view is a far cry from the functionality (Let alone *look*) of a Calendar view. I'd say hacking the core JavaScript is always something I'll prefer to keep away from for simpler maintainability.